# Angular - cannot find name 'window' / 'document' / 'localstorage'

Tags: angular, ecmascript-2016, ecmascript-2018

I've tried to update packages in an angular project but I'm getting many errors like "Cannot find name 'window'".
My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
  {
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2018",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "jszip": [
        "../node_modules/jszip/dist/jszip.min.js"
      ],
    }
  }
```

I tried es2016 but it doesn't make a difference.
Most answers that I found state that I have to "dom" to the lib array, but it's already there.
Any ideas why this happens?